# Three <li>, left center and right

Tags: html, css

I have three `<li>`. Unfortunately I cannot give them each their own class name (otherwise this would be easier).

I need to have one aligned to the left, one to the centre and one to the right. Is there any way to do this in CSS that can account for a variably sized `<ul>`?

Looking at other questions there is an option to use `li:last-child`. It would still be a problem for anyone using most IE's as support only exists in IE9.

Comment: I usually use `display: inline-block`. But you need a width for each li element.

Comment: 2 potential solutions provided with minimal markup.

Comment: the text-align-justify method works in IE5.5 if you use an extra element instead pseudo-after-element and use Conditionnal Comment with display:inline;zoom:1; i can upadte my answer and provide an exemple if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Fiddle Here http://jsfiddle.net/q4d9r/

Just use a width of `33%` and a `float:left` on your `li` items.

Set your `ul` to whatever `width` you want.

**EDIT:**

If you absolutely need to align them perfectly, you could always use `inline` styles on top of the above method.

#### http://jsfiddle.net/q4d9r/1/

```
<ul class="test">
    <li style="text-align:left">Item One</li>
    <li style="text-align:center">Item Two</li>
    <li style="text-align:right">Item Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's a bit of an odd question, I really want the text for the left `<li>` to be aligned to the left and the right one to the right. By increasing the width I have to make a choice as to where my text aligns

Comment: Well using the inline styles in the `edited` section resolves that... doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

[edit] by the time I post, the basic float was good enough, il leave answer for curious people :) [/edit]

there's 2 options i think of without using float, nor display:table; (in fact 4 options are avalaible):

1) display:flex;

2) text-align:justify; and some tunning:

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zcGmC

```
<ul class="flex">
  <li>flex me</li>
  <li>flex me</li>
  <li>flex me</li>
</ul>
<ul class="justify">
  <li>Justify me</li>
  <li>Justify me</li>
  <li>Justify me</li>
</ul>
```

```
.flex {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.justify {
  text-align:justify;
}
.justify:after {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
.justify li {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Nice :-) I've never used the `display:flex` method. I'll have to research that. New to CSS3?

Comment: it's quiet new indeed, some info here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ :)

Comment: Yeah, I was reading that before you posted :-P Thanks for the resource!

Comment: I really like this solution. I'm being a bit unreasonable here and asking for support for older browsers. I'm probably going to use it, maybe support older browsers another way.

Comment: with an extra element and conditionnal comment, you could include IE5.5 if you wish to use the text-align method